# How to Make matplotlib plt.fill_between Work Successfully

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, graphics

I've looked at a few posts on this but none have worked so far. I have a pandas dataframe, wp_df (excuse the bad column formatting, from copy/paste, but you get the idea):

```
wp  game_seconds_remaining game_half
18906  0.901082                     0.0  Overtime
18905  0.932920                    22.0  Overtime
18904  0.688796                    28.0  Overtime
18903  0.735589                    32.0  Overtime
18902  0.730993                    72.0  Overtime
...         ...                     ...       ...
18749  0.471634                  3664.0     Half1
18748  0.513039                  3702.0     Half1
18747  0.541705                  3743.0     Half1
18746  0.541372                  3776.0     Half1
18745  0.564195                  3813.0     Half1
```

I have graphed a scatter plot line from wp_df['wp'] using plt.plot(), resulting in the following image:
[image: Win Probability Chart]

I added some horizontal and vertical lines for visual ease. I would like to shade in regions between the red scatterplot line and the blue horizontal line at y = 0.50. --> Note that I have changed the x and y ticks. X ranges from the max values of wp_df['game_seconds_remaining] (in this case 3813.0) to 0.0 (the x axis is flipped), and y ranges from 0.0 to 1.0.

Anyhow, I want to shade the region between the red scatter line and the horizontal line at 0.50 on both sides of the horizontal line, with a different color on each. I tried going for `plt.fill_between(wp_df['wp'], 0.50, color='blue')` for one side of the shading, but this did not work out.

Any suggestions for how I could make this work?

Comment: You need x-values for `fill_between`. Maybe `plt.fill_between(wp_df['game_seconds_remaining'], wp_df['wp'], 0.50, color='blue', alpha=0.3)`.  (Adding an alpha helps to make the graph not being colored too strong.)

Comment: Nice, this worked well and filled in between the red line and the y=0.5 line. But, it filled on both sides of the line. Do I need to break up my line into segments > 0.50 and segments < 0.50, or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filling in a little extra based on your comment with JohanC.  You can use the `where` condition of `fill_between` to specify the specific blocks to fill.  There's a nice example [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/pyplots/whats_new_98_4_fill_between.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-whats-new-98-4-fill-between-py), but here's an example more similar to your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(200)
y = np.concatenate((np.random.randint(0,50,50), np.random.randint(50,100,50),
                    np.random.randint(0,50,50), np.random.randint(50,100,50)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,3.5))

ax.plot(x, y, color='red')
ax.axhline(50,0,200,color='blue')

ax.fill_between(x,y,50,where=(y<50), alpha=.3, color='orange')
ax.fill_between(x,y,50,where=(y>=50), alpha=.3, color='blue')
```

[image]

So if you have one condition with *two* options (i.e. above or below 50), you can use *two* calls to `fill_between`.  `y<50` and `y>=50` are boolean arrays denoting the points where `y` is above and below 50.  So note that the two calls fill 4 different areas of the plot here.

The code from @JohanC in the comment should be simply modified to replicate the above!

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked amazing. Some of the areas were not filled in perfectly, but I just added `interpolate=True` and it works as expected.